# slowness of angular.js web

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've almost finished my first angular.js app. Currently I'm trying to optimize page speed. Whole app is single page app so pages content is loading thew ajax. Initial load time on computer is around 5 seconds(might be problem but now it's ok). Other pages are loading in 200-400ms(mostly time for first byte takes 300ms), so it's quite fast.

Problem is load time on mobile devices. It's starting from 10 seconds to 20 maybe on low ram phones even more. What should I do? I compressed all scrips, styles, merged them into 1 file. When I make a test on webpagetest.org I got marks C A A A B so it's good, also on gtmetrix.com I got PageSpeed Score
(97%),YSlow Score(87%). Huh?

Problem might be in size of page. I'm transfering 1.4mb on first load. Scripts has around 600kb, css 340kb(but it's all minified). I'm using angular-material which has around 200kb.

What should I do? I tried do optimize everything what I found on google, but it doesn't seems to help much. Is there any other way what can I improve or it's lost and it gonna be as slow as it is forever?

Comment: Have you consider lazy loading?

Comment: thanks, I will take a look later but it looks promising.

Comment: Are you minified youre html, css, and js to single file each?

Comment: yes it's all minified.

Comment: what's the back-end? node, meteor, asp.net? If ASP.NET, make sure you build for "release" mode.

Comment: back-end is php(more precisely laravel framework), but I don't think that's the problem. Ajax requests are fast enough.

Comment: I use uncss to strip unnessary css. also I dont bundle angular and jquery, keep them on google cdn, so they can load parallel.